# "Product Info" Field in payU Form

Tags: forms, e-commerce, payment-gateway, payu

In payU's sample code;

```
    <form action="<%= action1 %>" method="post" name="payuForm">
      <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<%= merchant_key %>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<%= hash %>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="<%= txnid %>" />
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><b>Mandatory Parameters</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Amount: </td>
          <td><input name="amount" value="<%= (empty(params.get("amount"))) ? "" : params.get("amount") %>" /></td>
          <td>First Name: </td>
          <td><input name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<%= (empty(params.get("firstname"))) ? "" : params.get("firstname") %>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Email: </td>
          <td><input name="email" id="email" value="<%= (empty(params.get("email"))) ? "" : params.get("email") %>" /></td>
          <td>Phone: </td>
          <td><input name="phone" value="<%= (empty(params.get("phone"))) ? "" : params.get("phone") %>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Product Info: </td>
          <td colspan="3"><input name="productinfo" value="<%= (empty(params.get("productinfo"))) ? "" : params.get("productinfo") %>" size="64" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Success URI: </td>
          <td colspan="3"><input name="surl" value="<%= (empty(params.get("surl"))) ? "" : params.get("surl") %>" size="64" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Failure URI: </td>
          <td colspan="3"><input name="furl" value="<%= (empty(params.get("furl"))) ? "" : params.get("furl") %>" size="64" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><b>Optional Parameters</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Last Name: </td>
          <td><input name="lastname" id="lastname" value="<%= (empty(params.get("lastname"))) ? "" : params.get("lastname") %>" /></td>
          <td>Cancel URI: </td>
          <td><input name="curl" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Address1: </td>
          <td><input name="address1" value="<%= (empty(params.get("address1"))) ? "" : params.get("address1") %>" /></td>
          <td>Address2: </td>
          <td><input name="address2" value="<%= (empty(params.get("address2"))) ? "" : params.get("address2") %>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>City: </td>
          <td><input name="city" value="<%= (empty(params.get("city"))) ? "" : params.get("city") %>" /></td>
          <td>State: </td>
          <td><input name="state" value="<%= (empty(params.get("state"))) ? "" : params.get("state") %>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Country: </td>
          <td><input name="country" value="<%= (empty(params.get("country"))) ? "" : params.get("country") %>" /></td>
          <td>Zipcode: </td>
          <td><input name="zipcode" value="<%= (empty(params.get("zipcode"))) ? "" : params.get("zipcode") %>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>UDF1: </td>
          <td><input name="udf1" value="<%= (empty(params.get("udf1"))) ? "" : params.get("udf1") %>" /></td>
          <td>UDF2: </td>
          <td><input name="udf2" value="<%= (empty(params.get("udf2"))) ? "" : params.get("udf2") %>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>UDF3: </td>
          <td><input name="udf3" value="<%= (empty(params.get("udf3"))) ? "" : params.get("udf3") %>" /></td>
          <td>UDF4: </td>
          <td><input name="udf4" value="<%= (empty(params.get("udf4"))) ? "" : params.get("udf4") %>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>UDF5: </td>
          <td><input name="udf5" value="<%= (empty(params.get("udf5"))) ? "" : params.get("udf5") %>" /></td>
          <td>PG: </td>
          <td><input name="pg" value="<%= (empty(params.get("pg"))) ? "" : params.get("pg") %>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <% if(empty(hash)){ %>
            <td colspan="4"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
          <% } %>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

the field 'product info' looks like;

```
        <tr>
          <td>Product Info: </td>
          <td colspan="3"><input name="productinfo" value="<%= (empty(params.get("productinfo"))) ? "" : params.get("productinfo") %>" size="64" /></td>
        </tr>
```

but in "PayUMoney Integration Document", 'product info' described as;

> Product Info: It is a json encoded array of various payment parts where each part contains ‘name’, ‘description’, ‘value’ and
>   ‘isRequired’ fields. JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a
>   lightweight data- interchange format. It is easy for humans to read
>   and write. It is easy for machines to parse and generate.

now I'm confused, in form, how can I submit a json file. If i submit form like; [image: submit form]

payU returns me with error;

[image: error page]

Comment: Can you post your salt key?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct product info is meant to send information about products in JSON format. In practical(real transaction) you would populate that JSON from backend or while loading some similar code as mentioned in your sample and it wont be filled manually.

For testing purpose you can do away with JSON and simply put "product_info" as the value of "productinfo" field. It should work.